# Finding a directory or file without name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, io

We have a some files or directories with their absolute paths.
These files or directories will be renamed in a process. We can't get the new names from the process at all, but we have the root directory full name(full absolute path)
Now, I wanna find that items again
Is there a unique key or something for directories or files to find them without the exact name?

Comment: Do you mean like using a MD5 hash to create a unique identifier?

Comment: @failedprogramming: Yes

Comment: Answer by asveikau may help if Id doesn't change during rename... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162164/does-windows-have-inode-numbers-like-linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is nothing directly available on regular NTFS from C# code to do so.

You can

- compute some sort of hashes of files yourself + size check to find them again after rename (if they simply renamed)
- use events from [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to track file movements
- add [alternative streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604960/ntfs-alternate-data-streams-net) to files if they will not be stripped by "the process" to use as custom markers.

Comment: The files or directories may rename or moved within the root directory.