# How to get the File ID of a file or folder in on Windows 10 command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to know the *File ID* (on Linux etx-filesystem it would be called *Inode number*) of some files on Windows 10. Could be in a gui but would be better on command line.

A workaround would be to use *bash* (e.g. git-bash or cygwin) with `ls -i`. But I would prefere a windows specific solution.

Comment: `fsutil file queryfileid`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the Windows command prompt

```
fsutil file queryfileid <filename>
```

Looks like that wildcards not supported.

Comment: G:\My Drive>fsutil file queryfileid old-list.xlsx
File ID is 0x00000000000000000000000000000000