# How to determine if two file are hard-linked to the same data?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, hardlink

I've written an extension method for the `System.IO.FileInfo` class to create hard-link and it goes like this:

```cs
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool CreateHardLink(string lpFileName, string lpExistingFileName, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);

public static void CreateHardLink(this FileInfo file, string destination) {
    CreateHardLink(destination, file.FullName, IntPtr.Zero);
}

// Usage:
fileInfo.CreateHardLink(@".\hardLinkCopy.txt");
```

The method works fine, but I'd like to make some unit tests just for the sake of it. So how can I assert that a file x and another file y are linked to the same data?

I came up with some ways to test it:

- **Check if data is consistent throughout changes** Since creating a hard-link copy is just giving a second name to a file, any modification done to the first instance will be reflected on the second one, and vice-versa. If the data stay consistent between two files despite modification, it's safe to assume that these files are both hard-linked to the same data.
- **Assert that the creation of an hard-link doesn't affect the parent folder's size.** Since a hard-link copy doesn't copy any data on disk, the parent directory shouldn't get any heavier. If upon calling the method a new file is created with the same content as the original file, and the parent folder didn't change in size (or gain less than what a normal copy would do), the new file must be a hard-link copy.

However, these methods smell. There's got to be at least one build-in method somewhere in the OS to check if two files point to the same data on disk!

Anyone could share a lead?

Comment: You may be able to get an "inode" like ID of the file and check if it is equivalent. See asveikau's answer on [Does Windows have Inode Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162164/does-windows-have-inode-numbers-like-linux). Apparently this can also be checked by [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162664/how-to-get-the-file-id-of-a-file-or-folder-in-on-windows-10-command-line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following Bennett Yeo's suggestion, I found the following :

There's no direct way to check if two files are linked to the same data but we can make our own methods by comparing the file's unique id (or inode in UNIX-based system). In my understanding, this value serves as an index to the actual content on disk.

Bennett also linked [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162164/does-windows-have-inode-numbers-like-linux), which gave me two way to get a file's unique ID:

1. The linked answer proposed calling `GetFileInformationByHandle` from `kernel32.dll`. As the method's name implies, I must first get a handle for the file but whenever I try to get one, an exception is thrown saying that the targeted file is used by another process.
2. And, lastly, by using the command `fsutil file queryfileid <filename>` ([Credit to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45092571/8729475)).

The second method work for me, so I wrote the following code:

```cs
private static string InvokeShellAndGetOutput(string fileName, string arguments) {
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    p.Start();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
    return output;
}

public static long GetFileId(this FileInfo fileInfo) {
    // Call "fsutil" to get the unique file id
    string output = InvokeShellAndGetOutput("fsutil", $"file queryfileid {fileInfo.FullName}");

    // Remove the following characters: "File ID is " and the EOL at the end. The remaining string is an hex string with the "0x" prefix.
    string parsedOutput = output.Remove(0, 11).Trim();
    return Convert.ToInt64(parsedOutput, 16); ;
}

public static bool IsHardlinkedToSameData(this FileInfo fileInfo, FileInfo otherFileInfo) {
    return fileInfo.GetFileId() == otherFileInfo.GetFileId();
}
```

It's patchy but I feel it's already more reliable than my previous ideas. As long as the host running the test has "fsutil" installed, it should work.

Any more reliable solutions are still welcomed.